# What is the point of ZXing.BarcodeWriter in a Xamarin PCL?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, zxing

I've tried implementing a Xamarin.Forms function to set the source of an `Image` using ZXing, similar to:
[ZXing QR Code Generation in Xamarin Forms PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249911/zxing-qr-code-generation-in-xamarin-forms-pcl)

I've read a number of threads on Github and Xamarin Forums where people have attempted the same and are having the same issue as me: ending up with a blank image, despite the byte array returned by `BarcodeWriter.Write` seemingly having stuff in there.

And the usual resolution to all these threads ends up being using the ZXing.Mobile together with a dependency service to provide platform specific functions instead (with the exception of Allister, who claims to have it working using a `ContentView` on Android at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47861/zxing-net-mobile-barcodewriter-in-xamarin-forms-pcl).

**So my question is:**
What even is the point of the ZXing common library? Can the byte array returned from `BarcodeWriter.Write` be used to actually produce an image? Perhaps by passing it through some platform specific function?

I'm sure I'll end up going down the platform specific route myself, but I need to know why the last few hours of my day have gone to waste battling this issue.

Comment: this seems like a design question you should ask the author of the library, not us

Comment: Precisely why I also asked if the byte array generated can then be put to platform specific use. As in, has anyone been able to successfully do it...